# Python3.4.1 LINUX - from pip import main raises ImportError: Cannot import name 'main'

Tags: pip, zlib, python-3.4, libz

I'm using a server for which I am not root, and I have several scripts requiring Python 3.4.1.  I built the software from the source tarball using the following syntax

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME
$ make
$ make install
```

The software installed successfully, as I was able to launch `python3` after modifying my `.bash_profile` to look in `$HOME/bin`.  However, Pip was not so lucky.

```
$ pip3.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scnorton/bin/pip3.4", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

When I tried to run `python3 get-pip.py`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 17474, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 17466, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 17406, in bootstrap
    import pip
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

I have checked the /usr/lib64 directory and concluded that zlib is installed on the server.  I even executed the command `module load zlib-1.2.8-1` and tried reinstalling pip again, with no luck.  Could the problem be that Python3.4.1 is installed as a 32-bit application?  If so, where can I go to get 64-bit Python3.4.1 for Linux?